# mongodb error: ReferenceError: ismmaster is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm now making node.js application using express.js.

I use grid-stream, mongoose, multer to handle files.

I googled about this error but couldn't find answers.

Please let me know about this problem.

[server router code]

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
router.all('/uploads', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.body);
console.log(req.files);

var dirname = require('path').dirname(__dirname);
var filename = req.files.file2.name;
var path = req.files.file2.path;
var type = req.files.file2.mimetype;

var read_stream =  fs.createReadStream(dirname + '/bin/' + path);
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
conn.once('open', function () {
    console.log("open");
    var gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    // all set!
    console.log("test");
    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: "test.png"
    });
    console.log("test");
    read_stream.pipe(writestream);
});
Model.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
});
mongoose.disconnect();
```

});

[error code]

```
/usr/local/bin/node www
{ title: '11',
  description: '11',
  price: '50',
  reqNumber: '50',
  file1: 'kuro.jpg' }
{ file2: 
   { fieldname: 'file2',
     originalname: 'kuro.jpg',
     name: '7d15b68dea3a43e3701b4398662e434f.jpg',
     encoding: '7bit',
     mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
     path: 'uploads/7d15b68dea3a43e3701b4398662e434f.jpg',
     extension: 'jpg',
     size: 80127,
     truncated: false,
     buffer: null } }
open
test
/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:274
      process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
ReferenceError: ismmaster is not defined
at new ServerCapabilities (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topology_base.js:98:32)
at Server.capabilities (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:300:26)
at Collection.listIndexes (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1094:29)
at Db.indexInformation (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1220:25)
at Db.ensureIndex (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:781:8)
at Collection.ensureIndex (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1133:13)
at GridStore.open (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/gridfs/grid_store.js:189:16)
at GridWriteStream._open (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/gridfs-stream/lib/writestream.js:96:14)
at new GridWriteStream (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/gridfs-stream/lib/writestream.js:72:7)
at Grid.createWriteStream (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/gridfs-stream/lib/index.js:42:10)
at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/routes/index.js:117:31)
at NativeConnection.g (events.js:199:16)
at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:129:20)
at open (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:485:10)
at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (/Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:494:5)
at /Users/nuko/WebstormProjects/pliky/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:453:10

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/isMaster/#isMaster.ismaster  Here's the MongoDB documentation that is associated with your error.  Did you, by accident, alter one of the Mongo methods?  possibly try to check your log.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when you try to write to Slave servers in replica set.